# Convert String to Array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashmap

I have this String:

```
{count_scan=0, mac_address=E2:BF:FC:DF:3D:EE, minor=2233, major=42424},{count_scan=0, mac_address=V2:38:B2:3F:V6:BE, minor=2336, major=233}
```

or

```
[{count_scan=0, mac_address=E2:BF:FC:DF:3D:EE, minor=2233, major=42424},{count_scan=0, mac_address=V2:38:B2:3F:V6:BE, minor=2336, major=233}]
```

to array in Android?

Help,please regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to convert that data structure into a string -- such as JSON -- then save it as a string preference.

Or, write it out to a database or some other file. `SharedPreferences` are not really designed for complex data structures like this.

Comment: im try convert data_beacons.toString and my String result [{:name => "2",:id => 40222},{:name => "2", :id=> 2323}]  how to convert this string to new array when im need?

Comment: im try with   prev_beacons = Prefs_generico.getPref(context,"redar_beacons",null);  //RETURN STRING SAVE IN PREF   ,   List<String> return_beacons = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(prev_beacons));

            for (i = 0; i < return_beacons.size(); i++){
                return_beacons.get(i);
                Log.e("EL ARRAY QUE SE GUARDO ES ",String.valueOf(return_beacons));
            }  and, yes work but return bad : [[{:name => "2",:id => 40222},{:name => "2", :id=> 2323}]].... two[[]]

Comment: @Luis: There are plenty of JSON reading and writing APIs available, in Android (e.g., `org.json`) and third-party (e.g., GSON, Jackson). Use one to convert your model data to and from JSON.

Comment: im update this question...im convert array to String and need convert String to array ,regards!

Answer (score 0):

The docs give this as example:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
 editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
 editor.commit();
```

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

in your situation you need to loop over your List and then for each over each hashmap so you get the  item you want to put in the editor with some put method :)